# aws codepipeline webhook filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-codepipeline

I need to create an [aws codepipeline webhook](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codepipeline_webhook.html) to github using terraform that will filter the events coming from github to only events that are from a specific branch and prefix of files that are added, modified or deleted that are listed as strings in the `$.head_commit` path.

I have the filter on the branch working setting the `json_path` to `$.ref` and the `match="refs/head/development"` however I'm not clear what the syntax would be for matching on the string values in the added, modified and deleted lists would be.  I've tried a couple of examples that are listed on the [Json-Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) but so far I haven't been able to generate a `matchEquals` value that works.

Essentially I'm trying to get a version of this filter to work where *mypath* is what I'm trying to find an existence of inside the payload of the push event:

```
"filters": [
                {
                    "jsonPath": "$.head_commit.modified", 
                    "matchEquals": "^.*mypath.*$"
                }, 
                {
                    "jsonPath": "$.ref", 
                    "matchEquals": "refs/heads/development"
                }
            ]
```

Here is an abridged version of the payload sent by github

```
{
  "ref": "refs/heads/development",
  "head_commit": {
    "message": "Update README.md",
    "timestamp": "2019-06-26T10:03:38-07:00",
    "added": [

    ],
    "removed": [

    ],
    "modified": [
      "packages/mypath/README.md"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Update 6/27/2019**
After opening a support ticket it turns out that currently AWS doesn't support regex in the matchEquals property.  There is no eta on when it might be added but there is already an existing feature request in to support it.

Off to plan c "Restart the core somehow!"

Comment: do you have any news regarding this toppic?

Comment: I had to create a lambda function to send the github webhook to.  The function reads the payload and triggers the pipeline based off of the files that it sees were added, modified or deleted and the path that they fall under in the repo. I used an ALB as the entry point instead of a api gateway.  @nologin

Comment: good idea :) I'm currently using two repositories, each with it's own webhook.

Comment: @Aaron How do you prevent double executions on the same commit? I've created a lambda func that executes a pipeline when my modified files changes, but the built in CodePipeline Source Action Webhooks also fire, creating two executions. My only thought is that I set the branch of the Source Action  Webhooks setting to a dummy branch that is never pushed two, thus, freeing my lambda function to be my only trigger point. Wondering how/if you got around this.

Comment: @tnort173 I just removed the webhook for codepipeline and create one that points to a public ALB which hits a Lambda target.  Then the lambda takes the payload to determine which pipeline to trigger based off of the branch and file changes.  If you can give your codepipelines a naming convention that you can then generate based on the webhook payload it greatly simplifies the maintenance.

Comment: @Aaron Great! Thanks for your help. I'm wondering how you removed the webhook for codepipeline? I've been searching high and low and can't find any docs that suggest how to do it, in fact all the docs I've seen suggest it is required. I've looked at the CodePipeLine UI as well and I don't see any options to remove it.

Comment: @tnort173 I believe that you have to use the CLI.  You can also just delete the webhook in github for the repo and it will stop sending the requests to the pipeline.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you so much! For future readers, I was able to delete my codepipeline webhook via cli `aws codepipeline delete-webhook --name yournamehere`. It still shows in the AWS Codepipeline UI, but, tested and it's not triggering :D

Answer (score 0):

create a aws codepipeline webhook with filters bellow:

```json
"filters": [
    {
        "jsonPath": "$.pull_request.merged",
        "matchEquals": "true"
    },
    {
        "jsonPath": "$.pull_request.base.ref",
        "matchEquals": "main"
    },
    {
        "jsonPath": "$.pull_request.state",
        "matchEquals": "closed"
    }
]
```

And configure github webhook for "Pull requests"